# Add multi color gradient for different points in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have to add gradient inside a foot shape according to the value of a point inside the foot. I have X and Y coordinates of a point and a value is attached to it. According to the value I have to assign color gradient like in the picture below. Higher the value of a point, darker the area is
[image]

So far, I have created the foot and added 2 color gradient to the whole foot, but I am unable to add gradient like this in the picture. Below is what I have achieved. Please if anyone could help me to find any solution to this

[image]

Here is the [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni3mp4?file=src/app/scatter-plot/scatter-plot.component.ts)

Sample data :

```
 [
  {sensor: 0, value: 7.4, x: 108, y: 406}
  {sensor: 1, value: 8.1, x: 68, y: 412}
  {sensor: 2, value: 3.6, x: 108, y: 346}
  {sensor: 3, value: 4.5, x: 61, y: 350}
  {sensor: 4, value: 0.5, x: 108, y: 280}
  {sensor: 5, value: 1, x: 49, y: 288}
  {sensor: 6, value: 1, x: 122, y: 200}
  {sensor: 7, value: 0.5, x: 30, y: 218}
  {sensor: 8, value: 3.3, x: 140, y: 109}
  {sensor: 9, value: 3.4, x: 105, y: 114}
  {sensor: 10, value: 2.7, x: 78, y: 119}
  {sensor: 11, value: 2.3, x: 51, y: 124}
  {sensor: 12, value: 1.6, x: 22, y: 136}
  {sensor: 13, value: 3.5, x: 121, y: 41}
  {sensor: 14, value: 1.2, x: 85, y: 45}
  {sensor: 15, value: 1, x: 50, y: 59}
]
```

Comment: I suppose you need to convert your points into contours, draw them as <path>s and fill with the appropriate color

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I just want to add gradients and not the inner lines. Can you elaborate your answer more please?

Comment: Can you post some data here?

Comment: Heres my code (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni3mp4?file=src/app/scatter-plot/scatter-plot.component.ts)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I have also added sample data above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hit map with 'populated' data (based on average value of closest points):

Just add the mask of the foot contour...

```js
const data =  [
  {sensor: 0, value: 7.4, x: 108, y: 406},
  {sensor: 1, value: 8.1, x: 68, y: 412},
  {sensor: 2, value: 3.6, x: 108, y: 346},
  {sensor: 3, value: 4.5, x: 61, y: 350},
  {sensor: 4, value: 0.5, x: 108, y: 280},
  {sensor: 5, value: 1, x: 49, y: 288},
  {sensor: 6, value: 1, x: 122, y: 200},
  {sensor: 7, value: 0.5, x: 30, y: 218},
  {sensor: 8, value: 3.3, x: 140, y: 109},
  {sensor: 9, value: 3.4, x: 105, y: 114},
  {sensor: 10, value: 2.7, x: 78, y: 119},
  {sensor: 11, value: 2.3, x: 51, y: 124},
  {sensor: 12, value: 1.6, x: 22, y: 136},
  {sensor: 13, value: 3.5, x: 121, y: 41},
  {sensor: 14, value: 1.2, x: 85, y: 45},
  {sensor: 15, value: 1, x: 50, y: 59},
];

const populateData = (points, width, height, step) => {
    const populated = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x += step)
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y += step) {
        const distances = points.map(p => 
        ({...p, distance: Math.hypot(p.x - x, p.y - y)})).filter(d => d.distance < 100);
      const sum = distances.reduce((s, d) => s + 1 / d.distance, 0);
      const value = distances.reduce((a, d) => a + 1 / sum / d.distance * d.value, 0);
      populated.push({x, y, value});
    }
  return populated;  
};

const pd = populateData(data, 300, 500, 10);

const RECT_SIZE = 20;

const getColor = v => `rgb(255,${255 - v * 25},0)`

const svg = d3.select('svg');
pd.forEach(d => {
    svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', d.x - RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .attr('y', d.y - RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .attr('width', RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .attr('height', RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .style('fill', getColor(d.value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="500" />
```

Comment: colors work, but they are going out of the foot  boundary
https://i.stack.imgur.com/luwNE.png

Comment: You can create a mask from ordered boundary points and everything outside the mask will be invisible. If you don't find a solution in Stack Overlow, post another question and send me the link :)

Comment: I have posted another question, can you please look at it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208893/need-to-crop-the-area-outside-of-the-foot-svg-in-d3-js

Comment: Ohh I already found an answer to that and I didnt see your comment thats why I deleted it. I apologize. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @MalihaKhizer good luck with your project :)

Comment: can you please look at this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67277956/d3-js-create-an-outline-to-the-clipath-shape

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67279070/generate-16-colors-based-on-values-from-2-colors

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple plot with the data you provided:

If you have more points, it can be a more precise picture

```js
const data =  [
  {sensor: 0, value: 7.4, x: 108, y: 406},
  {sensor: 1, value: 8.1, x: 68, y: 412},
  {sensor: 2, value: 3.6, x: 108, y: 346},
  {sensor: 3, value: 4.5, x: 61, y: 350},
  {sensor: 4, value: 0.5, x: 108, y: 280},
  {sensor: 5, value: 1, x: 49, y: 288},
  {sensor: 6, value: 1, x: 122, y: 200},
  {sensor: 7, value: 0.5, x: 30, y: 218},
  {sensor: 8, value: 3.3, x: 140, y: 109},
  {sensor: 9, value: 3.4, x: 105, y: 114},
  {sensor: 10, value: 2.7, x: 78, y: 119},
  {sensor: 11, value: 2.3, x: 51, y: 124},
  {sensor: 12, value: 1.6, x: 22, y: 136},
  {sensor: 13, value: 3.5, x: 121, y: 41},
  {sensor: 14, value: 1.2, x: 85, y: 45},
  {sensor: 15, value: 1, x: 50, y: 59},
];

const RECT_SIZE = 20;

const getColor = v => `rgb(255,${255 - v * 25},0)`

const svg = d3.select('svg');
data.forEach(d => {
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', d.x - RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .attr('y', d.y - RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .attr('width', RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .attr('height', RECT_SIZE / 2)
    .style('fill', getColor(d.value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="500" />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this but the question still remains, we can plot the points but how to add the gradient. I already have this made but now I need to add gradient  instead of these circle or in your case, rectangles



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjZez.png