# Generate 16 colors based on values from 3 colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

### I'm trying to write function i n javascript, which can generate colors between three colors based on a given value.

Heres an explanation:

---

There are two colors : #0a0000, #ffaa03 & #ffffd5 
There are total 16 sensor e.g (0.2,0.9,2,2.3,3.5,4,7.7 … 27.7 ) - *this can be unordered* 
Now I am trying to find the min and the max from these sensor values, the lowest value would get #ffffd5 color, the highest value would get #0a0000 color, and the middle value will have #ffaa03 color. Now all the values in the middle will get the color between these two colors that are also close to the middle range color based on their value of how close they are to the minimum and maximum.

**UPDATE**

I have tried this below method but its giving wrong color values

```
let hex = '0123456789ABCDEF';

    let middleValue = this.maxValue / 2;
    if (x == this.minValue) {
      return '#ffffd5';
    } else if (x > middleValue - 1 && x < middleValue + 1) {
      return '#ffaa03';
    } else if (x == this.maxValue) {
      return '#0a0000';
    } else {
      if (x < middleValue - 1) {
        let perc = x * (middleValue - 1);
        let hexVal = hex[Math.round(16 * perc)];
        return '#FF' + hexVal + hexVal + '00';
      } else if (x > middleValue + 1) {
        let perc = x / (middleValue + 1) / 0.5 - 1;
        let hexVal = hex[hex.length - Math.round(16 * perc)];
        return '#' + hexVal + hexVal + '0000';
      }
    }
```

This is the image generated

[image]

Where as I want it to look similar to this depending on the values

[image]

Comment: If I understand it right, you have an array of values, and you need to assign a color to each value. The highest value will become red, the lowest - yellow, and the values between will be on pallete from red to yellow (orange e.t.c). Is that correct?

Comment: the highest value will be dark maroon, the lowest value would be very light yellow. The value in between will have color from yellow, dark yellow, orange, red, dark red and then maroon

Comment: Maroon is (128, 0, 0). What is dark maroon? 64, 0, 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the scale you need is a simple linear scale, with the domain as the extent of your data and the range as `["#ffffd5", "#0a0000"]`.

Here is an example, with the data unsorted (as you mentioned):

```js
const fakeData = d3.range(16).map(_ => d3.randomUniform(30)());
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(fakeData))
  .range(["#ffffd5", "#0a0000"]);
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(fakeData)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And here with the data sorted:

```js
const fakeData = d3.range(16).map(_ => d3.randomUniform(30)()).sort((a, b) => a - b);
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(fakeData))
  .range(["#ffffd5", "#0a0000"]);
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(fakeData)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, the image you posted doesn't match the colours you described (from `#ffffd5` to `#0a0000`). That said, you could alternatively use a sequential scale with another colour array, for instance:

```js
const fakeData = d3.range(16).map(_ => d3.randomUniform(30)()).sort((a, b) => a - b);
const scale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateReds)
  .domain(d3.extent(fakeData));
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(fakeData)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312494/convert-2d-shape-into-3d-in-d3-js-and-adjust-height-according-to-the-value-in-an

can you please check this question ?

Comment: I am stuck in another d3 question, would really appreciate if you can have a look and guide me with the solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312494/convert-2d-shape-into-3d-in-d3-js-and-adjust-height-according-to-the-value-in-an